# How do I display every products from a SQLite database on my website

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, mustache

I'm trying to make a web shop with a SQLITE database for a school project. The problem i'm currently encountering is that I can't manage to display all the products from the database on the website. To do so, I'm not allowed to use PHP so I need to do it through javascript. To generate each items, I'm using Mustache.

Here is my code :

HTML :

```html
        {{#items}}

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                    <a class="shop-item" href="#">
                        <div class="item-details">
                            <div>
                                <h5> {{Product_Name}}</h5>
                                <p>{{Product_Desc}}</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="item-price"><span class="unit">$</span>{{Product_Price}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <img src="#" alt="product"> -->
                    </a>
                </div>

    {{/items}}
```

Controller :

```js
module.exports = {
    'render' : render,
}


function getProduct(){
    const db = require('./../models/models').shopping;
    return  db.getItems();
}

async function render(req, res){
    const products = await getProduct();
    res.status(200).render('shopping', {
        //tableProduct : true,
        items : products
    })
}
```

Model :

```js
const db = require('./../../bin/dataBase');

const SELECT_PRODUCT_SQL ="SELECT Product_Price, Product_Name, Product_Desc FROM Product";

function getItems(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        db.all(SELECT_PRODUCT_SQL, (err,row) =>{
            if(err) return reject();
            if(row) return resolve(row);
            else return reject();
        })
    })
}


module.exports = {
    'getItems' : getItems
}
```

The error I'm currently having is : Error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItems' of undefined.

Comment: Have you tried doing `const db = require('./../models/models/shopping');` ?

Comment: Thank you ! it worked ! Have a good day